# Display updated count with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I created a function that shows the number of followers (taken directly from the database)

With ajax I can add a user to the database, but now I also would like to update the followers count number at the same time. But I'm not sure how to tackle this.

My code (simplified):

```
public function get_followers_ids( $user_id = 0 ) {

    ...

    $existing = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT followers FROM {$this->table} WHERE user_id = %d", absint( $user_id ) ) );      

    $followers = json_decode( $existing, true );

    return ( $followers );

}
```

Grab count

```
public function followers_count( $user_id = 0 ) {

    $ids = $this->get_followers_ids( $user_id );

    $follower_count = count( $ids ); 

    return $follower_count; 

}
```

In the actual display function, I simply add it as

```
$follower_count = $this->followers_count( get_current_user_id() );

echo sprintf( esc_html__( 'Followers %s', 'text-domain' ), '<span class="count-followers">'. $follower_count_users .'</span>' );
```

AJAX Callback

```
public function addon_ajax_follow_me() {

    check_ajax_referer( '', '' );   

    //  how to connect the ajax callback to update the follower count?

    wp_die();   

}
```

Comment: `UPDATE {$this->table} set followers = followers + 1 WHERE user_id = %d` execute this query also.

Comment: Not quite working unless I do something wrong. I created an extra function inside the ajax call `$this->update_counts();` In that function I used `$updated = $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE {$this->table} SET followers = followers + 1 WHERE user_id = %d", $args['user_id'] );  return $updated;` Any further ideas?

Comment: `$args['user_id']` is string convert it to integer using `intval($args['user_id'])` and try again.

Comment: I found a better solution. I only needed to add the following code inside the ajax success function: `var numfollowers = parseInt($('.count-followers').html()) + 1;
          $('.count-followers').html(numfollowers);`